# How to display total number of specs executed when running protractor tests in parallel?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-spec-reporter

I have a set of automated tests that use protractor/jasmine, and are written in typescript. When the tests finish running, I see this message in the console:

```
Executed 426 of 426 specs SUCCESS in 16 mins 36 secs.
```

I recently updated my tests to run in parallel, with this configuration:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
      ],
    },
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 3
  }
```

Now, as each test finishes, each web-driver instance reports the number of specs executed:

```
12:51:37  ------------------------------------
12:51:37  
12:51:37  [17:51:37] I/testLogger - [chrome #01-36] PID: 693
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] Specs: /opt/app/typeScript/specs/spec1.js
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] 
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] [17:51:22] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://selenium.local:4444/wd/hub
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] Jasmine started
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] 
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36]  Test 1
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36]     ��� Step 1
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36]     ��� Step 2
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36]     ��� Step 3
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36]     ��� Step 4
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] 
12:51:37  [chrome #01-36] Executed 4 of 4 specs SUCCESS in 10 secs.
12:51:37  
12:51:37  [17:51:37] I/testLogger - 
12:51:37  
12:51:37  [17:51:37] I/launcher - 3 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
12:51:48  ......[17:51:48] I/testLogger - 
12:51:48  ------------------------------------
12:51:48  
12:51:48  [17:51:48] I/testLogger - [chrome #01-37] PID: 708
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] Specs: /opt/app/typeScript/specs/spec2.js
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] 
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] [17:51:27] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://selenium.local:4444/wd/hub
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] Jasmine started
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] 
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37]   Test 2
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37]     ��� Step 1
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37]     ��� Step 2
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37]     ��� Step 3
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37]     ��� Step 4
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] 
12:51:48  [chrome #01-37] Executed 4 of 4 specs SUCCESS in 17 secs.
```

My Question:
With my tests running in parallel, how can I get the console to output the total number of specs executed, instead of just the number of specs executed per instance of a web-driver? In other words, I want to keep my tests running in parallel and have it show me this message at the end:

```
Executed 426 of 426 specs SUCCESS in 16 mins 36 secs.
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible without rewriting something in node_modules, every protractor page is a separate object.

Comment: Darn. I guess I'm just looking for a quick way to display all the tests that were run, even if I am running my tests in parallel.